# Very newbie question - How to make a new source file and call it main.rs?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just started learning rust programming language with zero experience in programming whatsoever. I'm following the book step by step guide and I'm already stuck at the hello world part (chapter 1.2) where it starts with

> Next, make a new source file and call it main.rs

How can I do that? I'm using Visual Studio Code with the integrated terminal.

Comment: So you are asking how to create a file in visual studio code ? That nothing link to rust.

Comment: I actually dont know what 'make a new source file' stands for and how to do it.
I tried making a new file with vscode in the projects/hello_world directory and named it main.rs, copied the helloworld rust code and saved the file, but next when I enter the command rustc main.rs it says:
error: couldn't read "main.rs": No such file or directory (os error 2)
error: aborting due to previous error

Comment: I guess this is more about rust than visual studio

Comment: when you type `rustc main.rs` you must be in the directory where `main.rs` exist. A source file is just a file, we call it source because its contains the source code. You did well by creating a file and rename it. But If you use windows or linux you should before learn some basic skill about how to use your operating system. If you go without have this basic you will have a lot of trouble. You have a lot to learn.

Comment: Thanks @Stargateur! I appreciate your answers, in the end I did well with this hello world thing. When you refer to basic skills about using my operating system what else do you actually mean? I'm on a mac by the way and I'm learning how to use the command line tools at the moment.

Comment: "I'm learning how to use the command line tools at the moment." this exactly, `error: couldn't read "main.rs": No such file or directory (os error 2)` should have point out the problem, this kind of error is very basic and fast to understand when you have done some code.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is to create a new Rust project. I assume that you want a binary project. Type in your terminal:

```
cargo new --bin [the name of your project]
```

And you then have all you need for your Rust project.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the directory you want to create the file, then enter `touch main.rs` that should create a new file in the directory.